# Can ants sense food from a long distance?

Tags: zoology, entomology, food, sensation, ant

I recently had ants find and then swarm to a food container that I put down on a desk. I'm curious as to whether an ant would have needed to get lucky (i.e., discovering the food after crawling up the desk) or ants have the ability to sense food from a distance.

I'm skeptical of believing that ants simply scout around until finding food; I'll use this case as an example:

- My room has had no food or drink in it for weeks, so the area wouldn't be a "hotspot" for ants to be interested in.
- I put the mostly empty food container down on my clean desk and turned my lamp off to work on the computer. No more than 2 hours later did I turn my light back on to discover a trail of ants swarming to the container I put down. It happened pretty quickly.
- The desk is high, standing on four thin legs. I find it difficult to believe that an ant would crawl up the desk as often as a 2 hour time frame to scout for food, for the message to be passed to the colony so quickly.

I've been curious about this scenario for a long time. So my question:

**Can ants sense food from a long distance?** If so, how does it work? If not, how is the phenomena (ants locating food quickly in unlikely places) explained?

Comment: You can detect food at a distance too, it is called smell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ants follow odor cues in the wind.  A study by [Wolf and Wehner (2000)](http://jeb.biologists.org/content/203/5/857.full.pdf) manipulated ant antennae and wind direction to show that ants followed odor plumes on the wind. A more recent study by [Buehlmann et al. (2014)](http://www.cell.com/current-biology/abstract/S0960-9822(14)00254-1) showed that desert ants of the genus *Cataglyphis* cued in on linoleic acid, a so-called necromone (death scent) released by dying insects. Here's a [popular article](http://theweek.com/article/index/259714/how-ants-use-death-signals-to-scavenge-for-food) that summarizes the latter study.  Chances are good the ants are followed the odor plumes coming from your mostly empty food container.

**Literature Cited**

Buelhman, C. et al. 2014. Desert ants locate food by combining high sensitivitty to food odors with extensive crosswind runs. Current Biology 24: 960-964.

Wolf, H. and R. Wehner. 2000. Pinpointing food sources: Olfactory and anemotactic orientation in desert ants, *Cataglyphis fortis*.  Journal of Experimental Biology 203: 857-868.

Answer (score 5):

I'd also like to point out that ants leave a [trail which they patrol](http://dnr.wi.gov/wnrmag/html/stories/1999/jun99/ants.htm) so the food need not be detected from a far only by a single worker patrolling near a region. Once found they have various means to [initiate a swarm](http://readingpack.com/article/?i=8805a716ba380606ad0fc6c77ef86488c32552d1).

Comment: I'm actually a programmer with interests in developing some of the brain's intelligence in computing (Think Siri, but taught, not programmed) and the *Ants Swarm Like Brains Think* article that you linked just, in a few paragraphs, helped me understand more about the working of the brain than any article or chart that I could have studied. Neat reading, thanks!

Comment: @jt0dd if you would like to collaborate on a general intelligence Turing machine that's fine it's doable I'm at gmail but it's 10 or 20 years man hours requiring multiple programming paradigms

Comment: As well as being a system interface designer, and back-end software engineer, I'm a web developer. My skill as a programmer is in advanced JavaScript, now whether or not that's the best language for the job is debatable. My thing is planning the infrastructure and then envisioning a brilliant user interface for it. So I lack C++ or C# or Java programming skills that you're likely accustomed to. Email jonathan@evisiion.com, if you'd like to talk.